# Type Mismatch error when running VBA code to delete rows based on specific criteria

Tags: loops, if-statement, excel, type-mismatch, vba

I'm trying to delete some rows in an Excel sheet based on some specific criteria. At some point, it gives the following Type Mismatch error:

[image: ss]

As far as I understand from the partially created sheet, the error occurs inside DO loop at

```
Or Len(Cells(r, 1)) = 5 _
Or Int(Right(Cells(r, 1), 4)) > 4000 _
Or Cells(r, 3) = 0
```

part. What should I do to correct the error? Additionally, if you can recommend me an improvement in the code for a faster run, I'd really appreciate it. The full code is as follows:

```
Sub delrows()

Dim r, RowCount As Long
r = 2

ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Select
RowCount = UsedRange.Rows.Count
userresponse = MsgBox("You have " & RowCount & " rows", vbOKOnly, "Info")

Rows(RowCount).Delete Shift:=xlUp

' Trim spaces

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, searchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

' Delete surplus columns

Range("L:T,V:AA,AE:AG,AR:AR,AU:AU,AZ:AZ").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

' Delete surplus rows

Do
    If Left(Cells(r, 1), 1) = "D" _
       Or Left(Cells(r, 1), 1) = "H" _
       Or Left(Cells(r, 1), 1) = "I" _
       Or Left(Cells(r, 1), 2) = "MD" _
       Or Left(Cells(r, 1), 2) = "ND" _
       Or Left(Cells(r, 1), 3) = "MSF" _
       Or Left(Cells(r, 1), 5) = "MSGZZ" _
       Or Len(Cells(r, 1)) = 5 _
       Or Int(Right(Cells(r, 1), 4)) > 4000 _
       Or Cells(r, 3) = 0 Then
     Rows(r).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else: r = r + 1
    End If
Loop Until (r = RowCount)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `Or Int(Right(Cells(r, 1), 4))` is a concern, because it assumes that the portion of the cell contents that it's evaluating is a number.

If it turns out not to be a number, then the `Int()` function would throw the kind of type mismatch error you are seeing.

It would be better if you tested for whether it is in fact a number first, before applying the `Int()` function. You can use the `IsNumeric()` function to do so.